# Prolog Binary Addition Issue?

Tags: binary, prolog

I have this piece of homework that I have to write in Prolog.The requirement is to write a piece of code that does binary addition such as:

```
?- add([1,0,1],[1,1],X).
X = [0,0,0,1]
```

And so, this is the code that I came up with:

```
add([],[], _).
add([],Y, Z) :- append([], Y, Z).
add(X,[], Z) :- append(X,[],Z).
add([HX|TX],[HY|TY], Z) :-
    HX = 1,
    HY = 1,
    add(TX,TY, Z1),
    add([1],Z1, Z2),
    append([0],Z2,Z),!.
add([HX|TX],[HY,TY], Z) :-
    HX = 0,
    HY = 1,
    add(TX,TY,Z1),
    append([1],Z1, Z),!.
add([HX|TX],[HY|TY], Z) :-
    HX = 1,
    HY = 0,
    add(TX,TY,Z1),
    append([1],Z1, Z),!.
add([HX|TX],[HY,TY], Z) :-
    HX = 0,
    HY = 0,
    add(TX,TY,Z1),
    append([0],Z1, Z),!.
```

It seems to do what I needed, however, there are strange issues with it that I can not understand, so if someone could guide me to what I have done wrong, I would be glad.

Results:

```
?- add([1,1,1,1], [1,1],Z).
Z = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]. % this is correct

?- add([1], [1],Z).
Z = [0, 1]. % this is correct

?- add([1,1,0,1], [1,1],Z).
Z = [0, 1, 1, 1]. % this is correct

?- add([1],[0],Y).
Y = [1|_G7100]. % there is an error here, but its not the big issue.

?- add([1,0,1], [1,1],Z).   
false. % no results are returned.

    104 ?- add([0], [1],Z).
    false. % no results returned either
```

Problem:
Whenever there seems to be a 0 in the first binary list, under some conditions(still trying to figure them out), no results seems to be returned.but I can't seem to locate my error.Would be glad if someone can tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: Instead of add([HX|TX],[HY|TY], Z) :- HX = 1, HY = 1, ..., I guess add([1|TX],[1|TY], Z) :- would be more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 mistakes:

- Rule #1: Should be `add([],[],[]).` instead of `add([],[], _).`. This fails for equal-length lists.
- Rule #5 and #7: Should be `add([HX|TX],[HY|TY], Z)` instead of `add([HX|TX],[HY,TY], Z)`. This fails when the second list (`Y`) contains less than two elements.

Fix these and your code should run well: see [here](http://ideone.com/rNggO).

Answer (score 0):

I see you use 7 different rules, since you put the binary arithmetic
inside the rules. You can do with 6 different rules plus a start rule
as follows:

```
add2(AL, BL, CL) :-
   add2(AL, BL, 0, CL).

add2([A | AL], [B | BL], Carry, [C | CL]) :-
   X is (A + B + Carry),
   C is X rem 2,
   NewCarry is X // 2,
   add2(AL, BL, NewCarry, CL).
add2([], BL, 0, BL) :- !.
add2(AL, [], 0, AL) :- !.
add2([], [B | BL], Carry, [C | CL]) :-
   X is B + Carry,
   NewCarry is X // 2,
   C is X rem 2,
   add2([], BL, NewCarry, CL).
add2([A | AL], [], Carry, [C | CL]) :-
   X is A + Carry,
   NewCarry is X // 2,
   C is X rem 2,
   add2([], AL, NewCarry, CL).
add2([], [], Carry, [Carry]).
```

Here are some example runs:

```
?- add2([1,1,1,1], [1,1],Z).
Z = [0,1,0,0,1]
?- add2([1], [1],Z).
Z = [0,1]
?- add2([1,1,0,1], [1,1],Z).
Z = [0,1,1,1]
?- add2([1],[0],Y).
Y = [1]
?- add2([1,0,1], [1,1],Z).
Z = [0,0,0,1]
?- add2([0], [1],Z).
Z = [1]
```

Main advantage of the above solution, less invocations of add2/4 and
you could replace the //2 and rem 2, and do addition in some other 
number system as well.

P.S.: Code taken from [here](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/05_run/15_stdy/06_bench/09_programs/02_crypt/package.html).